# Absolute stability for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know the formula for asbolute stability is

$$|1+h\lambda|<1$$

but how does it work when $\lambda$ is non-negative?

I get a negative step which is wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work when $\lambda$ is non-negative. That's why we require that $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(\lambda)<0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the condition for the explicit Euler method. The implicit Euler method has $|1-hλ|^{-1}<1$, the implicit trapezoidal method has $\left|\frac{2+hλ}{2-hλ}\right|<1$ etc.

The condition states that processes that exponentially decay towards zero keep doing that under the numerical method, whatever the numerical decay rate.